# Unable to link Work Item to a PR after the latter was created

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a PR [that I can not show here for privacy reasons] for which the Azure Devops Task could not be linked at time of creation due to a permissions problem at the time.

- Adding a link to the work item in comments or in the Description has not "qualified" as having "linked" the work item
- it is not possible to Complete the task without that link in place

I saw in one of the old MS developer forum questions that one must link it during PR creation  [Work items are not linked to Git PR's](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/work-items-are-not-linked-to-git-pull-requests/144552)  That is an outright *flaw* in the process: it is disallowing addressing/fixing the situation. What is a workaround here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a button for "Work Items" on the right-nav below the list of reviewers. We have *many* such reviewers so that button is *not visible* until the page is scrolled down.

[image]